# Number animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I have wallet and points, whenever I redeem the points, I want to show the wallet amount increasing as shown in the following video.

[image]

For the coin animation I already have a Lottie for it and I know how to implement, but is there any built in packages I can use to show the number increasing?

Comment: you can use AnimatedBuilder widget with Tween class - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flutter team already made it for us. Your example is here.

```
class TweenDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TweenDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<TweenDemo> createState() => _TweenDemoState();
}

class _TweenDemoState extends State<TweenDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const Duration _duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
  static const double accountBalance = 1000000;
  late final AnimationController controller;
  late final Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration)
      ..addListener(() {
        // Marks the widget tree as dirty
        setState(() {});
      });
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: accountBalance).animate(controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tweens'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
              child: Text('\$${animation.value.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                switch (controller.status) {
                  AnimationStatus.completed => 'Buy a Mansion',
                  AnimationStatus.forward => 'Accruing...',
                  AnimationStatus.reverse => 'Spending...',
                  _ => 'Win the lottery',
                },
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                switch (controller.status) {
                  case AnimationStatus.completed:
                    controller.reverse();
                  default:
                    controller.forward();
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Output](https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/animations/#/basics/tweens) & Ref: [Flutter Animation](https://flutter.github.io/samples/animations.html)